# How could I use tinyMCE when editing a SlickGrid column?

Tags: tinymce, slickgrid

I would like to use **tinyMCE** with a custom **Slick Editor** outside of the table, or inside a dialog. It's just to enable rich text editing.

- Can I use this external plugin for a custom Slick Editor? I have not seen any example of usages like this.
- Is there any potential problems using this two plugins at the same time (injecting conflicting HTML for example or preventing some firing events)?

Comment: And how do you imagine that would look like? Inject a tinyMCE editor into a cell? Or into a whole row? Just asking because the tinyMCE editor is huge in width and height, but the cell/row isn't... Please share more details in your question.

Comment: The editor could be outside of the table, or inside a dialog it's just to enable rich text editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a jquery alias "jQuery_new" with a compatible version
- Register the new editor "TinyMCEEditor" & Add it into slick.editors.js
- Use it like this *{id: "column2", name: "Year", field: "year", editor: Slick.Editors.TinyMCE}*

  ```
  jQuery_new.extend(true, window, {
    "Slick": {
      "Editors": {
          (..)
          "TinyMCE": TinyMCEEditor
      }
  }});

  function TinyMCEEditor(args) {
  var $input, $wrapper;
  var defaultValue;
  var scope = this;

  this.guid = function () {
      function s4() {
          return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
              .toString(16)
              .substring(1);
      }
      return s4();
  },

  this.init = function () {
      var $container = jQuery_new(".container");
      var textAreaIdString = 'rich-editor-'+guid();

      $wrapper = jQuery_new("<DIV ID='rds-wrapper'/>").appendTo($container);
      $input = jQuery_new("<TEXTAREA id=" + textAreaIdString + "/>");
      $input.appendTo($wrapper);
      jQuery_new("#" +textAreaIdString).val( args.item[args.column.field] );

      var _this = this;
      tinymce.init({
          selector: "#"+textAreaIdString,
          forced_root_block : "",
          plugins : "save image imagetools",
          toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link image | save',
          save_onsavecallback: function() {
              jQuery_new("#" +textAreaIdString).val( this.getContent() );
              _this.save();
          }
      });

      $input.bind("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
      scope.position(args.position);
      $input.focus().select();
  };

  this.handleKeyDown = function (e) {
      if (e.which == jQuery_new.ui.keyCode.ENTER && e.ctrlKey) {
          scope.save();
      } else if (e.which == jQuery_new.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
          e.preventDefault();
          scope.cancel();
      } else if (e.which == jQuery_new.ui.keyCode.TAB && e.shiftKey) {
          e.preventDefault();
          args.grid.navigatePrev();
      } else if (e.which == jQuery_new.ui.keyCode.TAB) {
          e.preventDefault();
          args.grid.navigateNext();
      }
  };

  this.save = function () {
      args.commitChanges();
  };

  this.cancel = function () {
      $input.val(defaultValue);
      args.cancelChanges();
  };

  this.hide = function () {
      $wrapper.hide();
  };

  this.show = function () {
      $wrapper.show();
  };

  this.position = function (position) {
  };

  this.destroy = function () {
      $wrapper.remove();
  };

  this.focus = function () {
      $input.focus();
  };

  this.loadValue = function (item) {

      $input.val(defaultValue = item[args.column.field]);
      $input.select();
  };

  this.serializeValue = function () {
      return $input.val();
  };

  this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
      item[args.column.field] = state;
  };

  this.isValueChanged = function () {
      return (!($input.val() == "" && defaultValue == null)) && ($input.val() != defaultValue);
  };

  this.validate = function () {
      return {
          valid: true,
          msg: null
      };
  };

  this.init();
  }
  ```